# How can I connect from client to a server with unknown ip address using java?

Tags: java, networking, server, client

I want to make communication possible between my android application and java application. I'm using socket communication. As my laptop is connected to WiFi, It's IP address will be changing. So how can I connect to it?

Comment: how to use the host name? Can you be a bit elaborated? In layman's terms please. @WalterM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using [Dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS). The server would have to update the DNS records every time his IP changes. You can then connect using the server hostname e.g. `new Socket("fancyservername.dyndns.com",80);`

Comment: How to use it? Sorry for that. I'm completely new to this stuff. In layman's terms.

Comment: 1. Find a (free) DDNS Provider. 2. Register a subdomain from this provider. 3. Configure the server to update the dns record every time its IP changes (or time based, if you cant detect that the IP changed). For example a quick google search found https://www.changeip.com/services/free-dynamic-dns/ . They also offer a web-api here https://www.changeip.com/services/free-dynamic-dns/ that could be used to update the records

Comment: Can't I use wifi router to set domain name and use it?

Comment: If both devices are on the same network (and your router has this feature): yes. If they are connected over internet: no. Though some router may have an option to update DDNS records if there IP changes.